# Как сделать функцию на JS/JQuery, которая по нажатию кнопки выводит в теле документа нужный текст?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

У меня есть массив на JavaScript, состоящий из строк. У меня есть функция, которая выбирает из него случайный элемент.
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `<button onclick="func()">` в определённом месте документа выводился этот элемент, а при повторном нажатии исчезал, и появлялся другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

var h1 = document.getElementById('text');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
   h1.innerText = arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length)];
});
```

```html
<h1 id='text'></h1>
<input type='button' id='button' value='button'/>
```

Comment: А если не включать в результат `max` (сделать его _exclusive_), то не придётся делать `- 1` при вызове функции и `+ 1` в самой функции.

Comment: Немного не понял про exclusive, но +-1 убрал.

Comment: _exclusive_ в данном случае - это "не включая границу". _inclusive_ - соответственно, "включая границу". Если на примере: пусть `min` равно `1`, а `max` - `10`. Если `max` - exclusive, то результат будет от `0` до `9`. Если inclusive, то от `0` до `10`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо...

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как изменить стиль кнопки, записанной через `input`? `<button>` легко меняется в CSS, мне её использовать?

Comment: Кстати, не знаю, почему, но у меня этот код не работает. Я полностью его копирую, запускаю, и текст при нажатии не появляется. Пробовал в разных браузерах. Что может быть не так?

Comment: <html><body> конструкция есть?

Comment: Не принципиально использовать <input>. Можно и к <div> прикрутить onclick... Я лично кнопки дивами делаю (не знаю правильно это или нет)

Comment: Конечно, есть. Понял, input необязательно, спасибо. Всё-таки никакой реакции на нажатие

Comment: @PavelAntropov если у вас в HTML-коде скрипт расположен выше используемых элементов `#text` и `#button`, то код в скрипте нужно обернуть в `document.ready`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает